# "Member function must be called or its address taken in function" C++ error

Tags: c++, multithreading, borland-c++, bcc-compiler

I am writing a program in `C++` which works with threads. When I try to create a process I get the following error: `Member function must be called or its address taken in function`. Here is my code:

```
void PCB::createProcess(){
    asm cli
    this->stack = new unsigned[stackSize];

    stack[stackSize-1] = 0x200;             
    stack[stackSize-2] = FP_SEG(wrapper);
    stack[stackSize-3] = FP_OFF(wrapper);
    this->ss = FP_SEG(stack+stackSize-12);
    this->sp = FP_OFF(stack+stackSize-12);

    asm sti
}


void PCB::wrapper(){

    myThread->run();

    myThread->state = TERMINATED;
}
```

I get the error in these two lines:

```
stack[stackSize-2] = FP_SEG(wrapper);
stack[stackSize-3] = FP_OFF(wrapper);
```

I have tried everything. 
I have tried `(&(wrapper))`, `PCB::wrapper`, `&PCB::wrapper` and nothing helps, it just gives me more errors. `PCB` is the name of the class.

If anyone has an idea, please help.

Answer (score 0):

`FP_SEG` and `FP_OFF` are macros that extract the segment selector and the offset, respectively, from a pointer. That's how we manipulated pointers under DOS and early versions of Windows, twenty-plus years ago. Unless you're targeting some funky system that you haven't mention, they are totally inappropriate.

Since `PCB::wrapper` is a member function, a pointer to it is a pointer-to-member-function. It is **not** an ordinary function, so the compiler is right to complain that it can't make sense out of what the code is trying to do.

These days, multithreading is done with `std::thread`. You don't have to do that hacky stack manipulation; just pass the pointer-to-member-function and the `this` pointer to the constructor for `std::thread`.

```
std::thread thr(&PCB::wrapper, this);
```

Comment: I am writing some kind of a simple kernel of an operating system. It is supposed to register interrupts from the keyboard and display the pressed key to the console. But I am only at the beginning. I actually must use those macros, since we are using the '92. standard for C++, and such compiler.

Comment: Then you **must say so** in your question. And there is no '92 standard for C++ -- the first C++ standard was 1998. Regardless: a pointer-to-member-function is not a pointer, and you can't treat it like one. Write a normal function, and call that member function on an object.